# ESP8266 (Wemos D1 mini) analog thermistor

Tags: adc, esp8266, thermistor

I'm trying to connect my floor heating thermistor (NTC) to ESP8266 (at Wemos D1 mini board). But I'm unable to get good results.

I get an approximation formula from this table (after I input my values in). [calculation table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16LH9NlN-g8H9trhc14fWrZ_FpBwIi78SplIAFQcUNNI/edit?usp=sharing)

But I get 41°C (should be around 24) what is really not even close. So what could be bad?

My candidates for bug are:

1. I use 230k Ohm at 25°C in the table to calculate formula (10k
   thermistor+220k voltage divider)
2. I use 3.3V as the supply for NTC but wemos D1 A0 is maxed 3.2V (but how to fix it?)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution is quite simple (in my first schema I forget to add a resistor between A0 and GND) but I decided to replace 10k resistor with 20k trim pot so I can adjust to exact value). I hope this will help someone.